# ajax call MVC Spring Controller, Not Found error

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I have a MVC Spring controller. I call this ajax on page load.

```
$.ajax({
            type:       "get",
            url:        'custom/Service',
            data:       "note1=" + "11",
            dataType:   "json",
            async:   false,
            success:    function() {
                        alert("1");
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                if(xhr.status == 200 && xhr.statusText == 'parsererror'){
                    window.location.reload();
                } else {
                    alert(xhr.status+","+xhr.statusText);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            }    
        });
```

My controller is:

```
@RequestMapping("/custom")
public class CustomController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/Service", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String Service(
                @RequestParam("note1") String note1,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale,
                Model model) {
            String result = custom.Service(note1, request, response);
        System.out.println("result: " + result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The out put is correct in the console for the controller. But I get "Not Found" error. Here is the developers tool error: GET "MySite/custom/Service?note1=11" 404 (Not Found) . What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Service", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody String Service(
                @RequestParam("note1") String note1,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale,
                Model model) {
            String result = custom.Service(note1, request, response);
        return result;
    }
```

You can access the result in your ajax success function.

```
success:    function(result) {
                        alert(result);
            },
```

Comment: The path is correct. Because I can see the the output in the console.I used that path for other ajax calls in the project and it works.

Comment: you are returning result, is it correct? it must be a jsp name.

Comment: I just created a class and put all Mapping in that like this:@RequestMapping("/custom")
public class CustomController { @RequestMapping(value="/Service", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public String ServiceType(
   @RequestParam("note1") String note1,
   HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale,
   Model model) {
  String result = custom.Service(note1, request, response);
 System.out.println("result: " + result);
 return result;
}

Comment: No, controller should return JSP name, please recheck once.

Comment: What should I do if I want to get result content in my ajax call? How can I get result?

Comment: I want to access result in js code because I have to hide some things in the page. So, is there a way that I access result in in ajax success? I know that I can do that in jsp page, by accessing ${result}, too.

Comment: Updated my answer please check

Comment: I will change my code like yours to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add response body annotation to your return parameter

```
 public @ReponseBody String Service(
```

A spring controller doesn't have to return a view, it can return data, with the reposnsebody annotation. Your original code will look up the result variable as a jsp according to your view resolver settings.